# angular click firing twice using nativeElement.click?

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap

Calling `getNextQuestion` which is used till i have data.length in the form so on last element i show `save` button that invoke `saveChanges()` and that is being fired twice because of `this.closeBtn.nativeElement.click();` how can i resolve this issue and close bootstrap modal ?

main.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="questionForm" novalidate>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" *ngIf="showNextButton" [disabled]="!questionsOptionSelected" (change) ="handleChange(singleQuestion)" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getNextQuestion(singleQuestion)">Next Question</button>
                                <button type="button" *ngIf="showSaveButton" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" #closeBtn [disabled]="!questionsOptionSelected"  (click)="saveChanges(singleQuestion)">Save changes</button>
                              </div>               
 </form>
```

main.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { EventService} from './format-questions/format-questions.service'
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  questionForm: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('closeBtn', {static: false}) closeBtn: ElementRef;
  data: any;
  questions: any[] = [];
  singleQuestion: any[] = [];

  constructor(private dataService:ApiService, private eventService:EventService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.questionForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      alrgyDetls: formBuilder.group({
        ALLERGY_DETAILS: ['']
      }),
      curntText :this.formBuilder.group({
        CURRENT_TEXT: ['']
      }),
      DosesForm :this.formBuilder.group({
        TEXT_NUMBER: [''],
        TEXT_DATE: ['']
      }),
    });
  }
// nextQuestion button logic for single question event
 getNextQuestion(e: any){
  let formattedQuestion = {};
  this.questions.shift();
  formattedQuestion = this.formatSubQuestions(e.answerOption.subQuestion);
  if(formattedQuestion){
    this.questionsArray.push(formattedQuestion);
    this.questionsOptionSelected = false;
  }
   if(this.questions.length > 0){
      this.singleQuestion = this.questions[0];
      if(this.questions.length === 1) {
        this.showNextButton = false;
        this.showSaveButton = true;
    }
  }    
 }
 onSubmit(){
    this.FormValues = this.questionForm.value;
    console.log("Form", this.FormValues.value);
 }


  // save changes and emit data to format component
 saveChanges(e:any){
  this.getNextQuestion(e);
  this.eventService.setData(this.questionsArray);
  this.questions = [];
  this.singleQuestion = [];
  this.questionsArray = [];
  this.closeBtn.nativeElement.click();
 }
}
```

Comment: So you fire off `saveChanges()` when `#closeBtn` is clicked, which then at the end you expect to click the same button that fired off the same method that called the method in the first place? I have to ask, what are you expecting here?

Comment: @Chris W when `saveChanges` is clicked i have to invoke `getNextQuestion`  so last element run through logic and then close the modal window , i figured it out that `nativeElementClick` triggering `saveChanges` again , not sure if there is any other way to close modal window ?

Comment: Yes, there's plenty of ways to. From using `ViewChild` or however you're using bootstrap has an API call to dismiss it also. Are you using ng-bootstrap or something? I'm betting there's a quick one liner in the docs to do so.

Comment: @ChrisW. i am not using ng-bootstrap thats the problem and i can not change it we are using native bootstrap. there is `data-dismiss` but that is not working either to close the modal

Comment: You could do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577690/hide-bootstrap-modal-using-pure-javascript-on-click/52570205) (which would be simple to port into a typescript utility class and use renderer2 etc, or just use jquery like it does (though jquery is fugly in an angular app)

Comment: have you tried moving `#closeBtn` to `<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>` it appears you are having the `Save Changes` button clicked twice, once when the user clicks on it and again in the saveChanges() method.